# Deserialize json with different object types

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I get the following json from a httpresponse

```
{
"result": "success",
"team_registration": {
    "current_status": "executed",
    "expiration_time": "2012-07-18T21:29:43Z",
    "id": 609,
    "team_id": 50,
    }
}
```

How do I retreive the "result" as a string and the "team_registration" as a POJO (in Android) with Jackson?

Currently I have this:

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            String json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });

            result = (String) map.get("result");
            resultRegistration = (Registration) map.get("team_registration");
```

Registration class:

```
package be.radarwerk.app.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore;

public class Registration implements Serializable { // Todo implements parceable?
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int id;
private String currentStatus;
private Date expirationTime;

@JsonIgnore
private Volunteer volunteer;
@JsonIgnore
private Team team;

public Registration() {

}

public Registration(int id, String currentStatus, Volunteer volunteer,
        Team team) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.currentStatus = currentStatus;
    this.volunteer = volunteer;
    this.team = team;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getCurrentStatus() {
    return currentStatus;
}

public Volunteer getVolunteer() {
    return volunteer;
}

public Team getTeam() {
    return team;
}

public Date getExpirationTime() {
    return expirationTime;
    }


}
```

"result" as String works fine but for the "registration_moment" I get this exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Registration

I also tried casting it to a String in the same way as "result" and doing mapper.readValue on that string.
No success.

Any tips?

Comment: Show the code of your `Registration` class, please. Also, is there a common object between the different types of `result`?

Comment: You might want to try android-query (http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class should be deserialized automatically if you modify it like this (**Note! Jackson 2.1+ required**):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("team_id")
@JsonNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCaseWithUnderscoresStrategy)
public class Registration implements Serializable 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id;
    private String currentStatus;
    private Date expirationTime;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Volunteer volunteer;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Team team;

    public Registration() {        
    }

    // other code
}
```

Then, to deserialize in your code:

```
Registration registration;
final JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
if (node.get("result").textValue().equals("success"))
    registration = mapper.readObject(node.get("team_registration").traverse(),
        Registration.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Is it really necessary to create those two subclasses? The `result: succes` is only meant to check if the user is signed in and if the input was correct (the response results from scanning a QR code). Sounds strange to serialize `Registration` in `SuccessfulOperation` to me

Comment: Well, no, it is not necessary. It is just the cleanest solution I know when dealing with "polymorphic JSON" ;) You still did not show what your `Registration` class looks like.

Comment: OK, hold on, I'll edit my answer with a fully annotated class; what Jackson version are you using?

Comment: Jackson:1.9.12 I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Argh, 1.9.12??? The most recent version is 2.2.1! Upgrade :p My code will work with 2.1.x (edited), but I doubt it will with 1.9.12...

Comment: No problem! And good choice on Jackson... Android's JSON library is poor, to be honest

Comment: I used jackson before in college when creating a java webapp. Hestitated to try GSon but Jackson is doing great :)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems a bit odd to me. You should really be using the Android [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) class, that's what it's there for. Once you have a JSONObject (or JSONArray), you will need to iterate over it if you want to move elements into a different data structure, but that's very likely unnecessary.

In any event, here's some code (using [android-query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/)) to get you to a JSONObject:

```
String url = "whatever you want";
aq.ajax(url, JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void callback(String url, JSONArray json, AjaxStatus status) {
        if (json == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to retrieve JSON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
        else {
            try {
                JSONObject general = json.getJSONObject(0);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm really new with Android development. Are you suggesting to serialize the JSONObject as a `Registration` object afterwards?